# efficiency of linear seach and binary search done k times

Tags: algorithm, sorting

For which values of k is doing k linear searches more efficient than doing a merge sort and then doing k binary searches on an unsorted integer array?

I want to know if my solution is correct

big O of linear search is O(k*n)

big O of merge sort is O(nlogn)

big O of binary search is O(klogn)

TOTAL big O of merge sort and binary search: O(nlogn + klogn)

If k is much bigger than n, then O(nlogn + klogn) --> O(klogn)

Then, klogn < n for all k so then doing binary search is more efficient

If n is much bigger than k, then O(nlogn + klogn) --> O(nlogn)

Then, nlogn > kn (linear search is more efficient) when k < logn.
When k > logn, then doing binary search is more efficient.

Is this analysis correct?

Comment: In theory, might be. In practice, linear search beats the crap out of everything else for simple data types (like integers or references/pointers) up to *n* very large (easily in excess of 10-100k)

Comment: You have conveniently ignored all the constant factors, which are very low for linear search but moderate for binary search and pretty large for merge sort.

Comment: @dom0 what do you mean linear search beats everything? Binary search is amazingly better.

Comment: See harold's comment. Also note that computers have hierarchical memories both and prefetchers. Linear search is an optimal case for both of these, while sorting or binary search are not. This leads to linear search often beating binary search even on pre-sorted datasets. But yes - from a Big-O perspective sorting & bsearch is "amazingly better". However, in practice, they are not. **Big-O does not reflect practice, since it assumes a lot of things that don't hold true for computers of the last 2+ decades. In practice: measure it, don't rely on Big-O.** There are still good reasons to do Big O